# Spring Boot Security OAuth2 + Custom Permission Evaluator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring boot (1.5.3) oauth2 application that has secured URL's and methods. Method security is currently working via:
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_NAME')")

I'm now trying to add a custom PermissionEvaluator so that I can secure methods with 
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'typeName', 'permissionName')").

I'm enabling this functionality by extending GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, mode = 
AdviceMode.ASPECTJ, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration 
{

    @Autowired
    private MatterRepository matterRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MatterTeamMemberRepository matterTeamMemberRepository;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
      Map<String, Permission> permissionsMap = new HashMap<>();
      permissionsMap.put(ReadMatterPermission.class.getSimpleName(),
      new ReadMatterPermission(matterRepository, matterTeamMemberRepository));

      OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new 
      OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
      handler.setPermissionEvaluator(new 
          EntityPermissionEvaluator(permissionsMap));
      return handler;
    }
```

}

Note: PermissionEvaluator class omitted for brevity.

The problem I'm having is that hasPermission is sometimes invoked - most often it is not invoked. I suspect this is something to do with:

```
*Auto-configure an expression handler for method-level security (if the user 
* already has
* {@code @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity}).  
o.s.b.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.method.OAuth2MethodSecurityConfiguration
```

creating an instance of OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler before my configuration is processed.

Has anyone successfully injected a PermissionEvaluator into a spring boot oauth2 applicaion?

Thanks.

Comment: I disabled oauth2 autoconfiguration which made no difference so have eliminated that.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out not to be a spring security configuration issue. The issue was related to aspectj compiler configuration in the pom. Long story short, fully qualified class name of AnnotationSecurityAspect was incorrect:

```
org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aspectj.AnnotationSecurityAspect
```

instead of

```
org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aspectj.aspect.AnnotationSecurityAspect
```

causing @PreAuthorize annotations to be ignored. My understanding that @PreAuthorize("hasRole...") was working was wrong - confused by the fact that tests sometimes succeeded when run through Eclipse but never when run via mvn on the command line.

Comment: But how Spring created your expressionHandler if GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.getExpressionHandler() checks if any handler already exists and in your case it would be OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler, so your handler wouldn't be created..